# Transfering data between two rails servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, server

What I'm trying to do is to transfer my Company model that has a lot of associations, depots, products, users, owners, etc, to another database(server). I've tried cloning the company but it doesn't get the associations. How exactly can I get the Company data and it's children to the other database? I don't want to dump my data and restore it, I want to establish a connection between the two databases and be able to transfer what data I have from the first server to the second.

Comment: Aren't you better off using a data base level utility for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean exactly.

Comment: I mean that rather than use Rails to transfer the data, use a utility that operates on the data base level.  For example, if the servers are Mysql, you can use mysqldump (see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/). This is more reliable, as you'd be more certain to get an exact copy than doing this on the higher application level.

Comment: I'm using Postgres, is there something similar for postgres?

Comment: I don't know, but I just googled "postgres backup and restore" and it looks like there's a very simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest instead do this on the data base level rather than the application level.  This would result in a more reliably faithful copy of the data.

For Postgres, you can do the following (found at https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=postgres+backup+and+restore&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8):

```
Backup a local postgres database and restore to remote server using single command: 

$ pg_dump dbname | psql -h hostname dbname. ...
```